# Can maven resolve local resources whose folder structure changed?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am trying to migrate an existing project from an Ant project to a Maven project.
The Ant project had a structure of :

```
|-root
|---resources
|------foo
|------yaz
|---src
|------SomeFile.java
```

The Maven project has a structure of

```
|-root
|---src
|------main
|---------java
|------------SomeFile.java
|------test
|---------resources
|------------foo
|------------yaz
```

Unfortunately, the code has lots of explicit references to the "resources" folder. Some examples:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/resources/foo/bar.xml")

ApplicationContext context = 
   new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("resources/foo/baz.xml");

File file = new File("resources/yaz/blah.gif");

etc...
```

It would take a lot of effort to change all the references (and due to other business-rules, the code must remain in the 'resource' folder).  I was wondering if there was an easy way in maven to resolve the change in folder structure.  That way when JUnit tests run or the application is launched via IDE (Netbeans), it will correctly resolve the resources.

In other words, the code worked fine when in Ant, but broke after being moved to Maven because the resources have moved to a different folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should always reference files in the build area, not the source area. It appears that your maven build is not entirely replicating what the ant build was doing. Check the target/classses folder (the base for constructing the jar file later) and see at what location the resources files are. If wrong, either manipulate the source directory structure until you get what you want or use  pom element to set the right  - http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources

Answer (score 1):

When you build the war, put `src/main/resources` into `/target/resources` instead of `/target` directly.

[THIS PAGE](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) shows `outputDirectory` parameter which specifies the output folder for resources.

I think it would look something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what i can is is your source code wrong, cause you are referencing the resources folder which is part of the defaults.

So usually everything which is located int `src/main/resources` will be copied during the build to `target/classes` which means you need to reference such kind of resources like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/foo/bar.xml")

ApplicationContext context = 
   new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/foo/baz.xml");
```

But I'm not 100% sure if the above is really working. As far as i know it will only work if your resources is available via classpath which in case of a jar which contains the resources is not true.

Furthermore referencing resources as a file is the wrong way, cause if the result of your build is packaged into a jar you can't access the resources as a file. You need to go via

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().resourcesAsStream("/yaz/blah.gif");
```

but **NOT** like this:

```
File file = new File("/yaz/blah.gif");
```

which will not work.

If you really need to go with the structure of the project you need to add the supplemental resources folder via the [build helper maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) but i would suggest better going with default layouts in Maven.